# RxJS operator that waits for quiet period in event stream, but in case of busy event stream does not wait for ever

Tags: javascript, rxjs

The scenario:

- I have a stream of events, each event should result in the updated display of information (event stream is from websockets and the display is in a highcharts chart, but that is not important)
- For performance reasons, I do not want to trigger a UI update for each event.
- I would rather do the following:

  - When I receive an event I want to do the UI update only it is more than X milliseconds since the last update
  - But every Y milliseconds (Y > X) I want to do an update anyway, if there have been any incoming events
  - So I am looking for some kind of (combination of) RxJS operator that will rate-limit the event stream to emit an event only when a quiet period occurs (or the wait-for-quiet-period-maximum-time has been exceeded).
  - I.e. I want to wait for quiet periods, but not for ever.

How can I implement what I describe above?

I have looked at:

- https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/sampleTime
- https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounceTime
- ... and some other rxjs time/rate-limiting operators

Comment: I would use `debounce`, passing a notifier observable composed by merging the delayed source with a timer. I can look at writing an answer later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an operator to do what you want by using `debounce` and employing two timers in the composition of the notifier observable:

- a timer that emits X milliseconds after the source emits a value; and
- a timer that emits Y milliseconds after the observable returned by the operator emits a value.

See the snippet below. Comments within should explain how it works.

```js
const {
  ConnectableObservable,
  merge,
  MonoTypeOperatorFunction,
  Observable,
  of,
  Subject,
  Subscription,
  timer
} = rxjs;

const {
  concatMap,
  debounce,
  mapTo,
  publish,
  startWith,
  switchMap
} = rxjs.operators;

// The pipeable operator:

function waitUntilQuietButNotTooLong(
  quietDuration,
  tooLongDuration
) {

  return source => new Observable(observer => {

    let tooLongTimer;
    
    // Debounce the source using a notifier that emits after `quietDuration`
    // milliseconds since the last source emission or `tooLongDuration`
    // milliseconds since the observable returned by the operator last
    // emitted.

    const debounced = source.pipe(
      debounce(() => merge(
        timer(quietDuration),
        tooLongTimer
      ))
    );

    // Each time the source emits, `debounce` will subscribe to the notifier.
    // Use `publish` to create a `ConnectableObservable` so that the too-long
    // timer will continue independently of the subscription from `debounce`
    // implementation.

    tooLongTimer = debounced.pipe(
      startWith(undefined),
      switchMap(() => timer(tooLongDuration)),
      publish()
    );

    // Connect the `tooLongTimer` observable and subscribe the observer to
    // the `debounced` observable. Compose a subscription so that
    // unsubscribing from the observable returned by the operator will
    // disconnect from `tooLongTimer` and unsubscribe from `debounced`.

    const subscription = new Subscription();
    subscription.add(tooLongTimer.connect());
    subscription.add(debounced.subscribe(observer));
    return subscription;
  });
}

// For a harness, create a subject and apply the operator:

const since = Date.now();
const source = new Subject();
source.pipe(
  waitUntilQuietButNotTooLong(100, 500)
).subscribe(value => console.log(`received ${value} @ ${Date.now() - since} ms`));

// And create an observable that emits at a particular time and subscribe
// the subject to it:

const emissions = of(0, 50, 100, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000, 1050, 1100, 1150);
emissions.pipe(
  concatMap((value, index) => timer(new Date(since + value)).pipe(
    mapTo(index)
  ))
).subscribe(source);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can combine a `timer` with a `debounceTime` and use it to sample the original event stream:

```
let $tick = Rx.Observable.timer(100, 100);
let $updates = $events
                  .sample($tick.merge($events.debounceTime(30))
                  .distinctUntilChanged();
```

This will take an event every 100 milliseconds, but also if an event occurs before a 30 millisecond gap.

With `sample`, the values in the sampling stream are ignored. So this technique creates a sampling stream that includes both the time-based requirement and also the debouncing. Whenever either of these happens, it will take the latest value from the original stream.

Using `distinctUntilChanged` prevents events repeating consecutively with the same value if nothing changed. You may need to add a comparison function as an argument to `distinctUntilChanged` if your data is structured or otherwise can't be compared with `===`.

Comment: Whether or not there's any point depends upon the difference between the values of X and Y, I guess, but I'm tempted to give you +1 just because of the Laphroaig bottle.