# Which rxjs operator(s) do I use in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, reactive

I am pretty new to RxJs and looking for a way to sample/throttle (I haven't figured out the right word yet) events from a `Subject` in the following way

- rapid events in succession samples every `x` milliseconds
- `y` milliseconds of no events

The marble diagram would look like

```
    o         o          o o oo   o o          o         o
    ↓         ↓          ↓ ↓ ↓↓   ↓ ↓          ↓         ↓
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                             magic                           │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
       ↓         ↓         ↓  ↓  ↓  ↓  ↓          ↓         ↓
       o         o         o  o  o  o  o          o         o
```

What operator(s) would I use for this? Unfortunately `sampleTime`, `debounceTime` or `throttleTime` did not give me the right output.

Apologies in advanced for what may be a silly/beginner question.

Comment: Your question sounds very much like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50643440/6680611).

Comment: thank you! sorry i didnt find this in the search, but if it works for me, ill mark as dupe

Comment: I wouldn't have searched, either. Frankly, I'm really surprised to see two such questions so close together. Maybe the `debounceTimeWithinReason` operator I added to [`rxjs-etc`](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-etc/blob/master/source/operators/debounceTimeWithinReason.ts) is more useful that I thought.